# Does PySpark JSON parsing happen in Python or JVM?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

`sqlContext.read.json("...path.to.file...")`

I'm writing a Spark script in Python using pyspark. Does the JSON parsing happen in Python or on the JVM? If Python, does it use the C simplejson extension, or is it native Python?

I'm doing a **lot** of JSON parsing so performance here matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON parsing is done in the JVM and it's the fastest to load jsons to file.

But if you don't specify schema to `read.json`, then spark will probe all input files to find "superset" schema for the jsons. So if performance matters, first create small json file with sample documents, then gather schema from them:

```
schema = sqlContext.read.json("/path/to/small/file.json").schema
```

Then load your big dataset specyfying schema:

```
 df = sqlContext.read.json("/path/to/big/dataset", schema=schema)
```

Comment: You can also set the schema manually. In many cases you do not really need all of the fields so you can set a subset of the fields, build a schema and provide that schema directly

Comment: Yep, in my code I actually do `sqlContext.read.schema(...).json(...)`. I just simplified the example here :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you do sqlContext.read.json this is translated behind the scenes to an expression which is evaluated by scala code. This means the json parsing would be done by the JVM.